# Module found in ipython not other IDE (nolearn and lasagne)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I know this is a question arising from not understanding how Python works but I am stumped.

I have installed the nolearn and lasagne libs at /home/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages. There is a library called lasagne at sitepackages and also it is a subfolder of the nolearn folder.

When I open ipython notebook, I can run a program where this statement works fine:

from nolearn.lasagne import NeuralNet

but when ran from Pycharm....

```
    from nolearn.lasagne import NeuralNet
  File "/home/Desktop/Programming/python_scripts/pycharm/nolearn.py", line 9, in <module>
    from nolearn.lasagne import NeuralNet
ImportError: No module named lasagne
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are setting the correct interpreter for the project ?

Comment: The interpreter for pycharm is set to the python 2.7 from anaconda. Could the issue be that there is a lasagne folder and lasagne is a sub folder under nolearn?

Comment: Sorry I should've been more specific. Are you using a virtual environment and if so did you set your python interpreter tu that of that environment?

Comment: no no virtual environment.

Comment: Can you check what is the project interpreter in pycharm ? All the packages installed to the site packages of a particular interpreter are automatically imported by pycharm and should be available. 

The location of the interpreter will be in your pycharm preferences -> project interpreter

Comment: I think the embarrassing thing is that I had a file in the project called nolearn.py and I *THINK* that was what was being called -- and there was no nolearn.lasagne :'/  Thanks for being willing to help!